# Regular expression to find fractions while ignoring dates in Python

Tags: python

I need a regular expression to find fractions in the form `x/y` but ignore `dd/mm/yyyy`.

For example:

`"1/4 test test is the date for 2021/12/31, 1/3  1/5"` should return `["1/4", "1/3", "1/5"]`

Comment: How about splitting the text into tokens, then matching `x/y`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a method of splitting the string into a list of substrings and then iterating through that list and keeping the entries that qualify as fractions.

```
import re

def getFractions(string):
    fractions = []
    for split in string.split(' '):
        fractions.extend(re.findall(r'^[0-9]+/0*[1-9][0-9]*$',split))
    return fractions
```

```
>> getFractions('1/4 test test is the date for 2021/12/31 1/3 1/5')
['1/4', '1/3', '1/5']
```

```
>> getFractions('1/4 2010/43/32 1/3 1/53 4/32 9/34 34/9')
['1/4', '1/3', '1/53', '4/32', '9/34', '34/9']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex only, you need to use lookbehinds/lookaheads to mach start/end of string or spaces:

```
import re
text = '1/4 test test is the date for 2021/12/31, 1/3 1/5'
re.findall(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))(\b\d+/\d+\b)(?:(?=\s)|(?=$))', text)
```

Output:

```
['1/4', '1/3', '1/5']
```